# Get/Set scrollbar position of ultrawingrid

Tags: c#, infragistics

In my C# program, I have an `ultrawingrid` being filled from a `SQL CE` database. My refreshGrid() function is called after every related action that the user takes. The function calls another SQL query, saves the data to the datatable and sets this as the grid data source.

However my problem is that the vertical scrollbar position resets every time the refresh function is called - so the grid view resets back to the top of the grid.

My initial thought would be to save the scrollbar position as a variable, then after the refresh, set the scrollbar back to that position. But how would I do this? Or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Get the scroll position before the refresh, and set it afterwards.

```
var scrollPos = grid.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollPosition;
refresh();
grid.ActiveRowScrollRegion.ScrollPosition = scrollPos;
```

Comment: It will not work in case when rowsNumberBeforeRefresh > rowsNumberAfterRefresh